# Breakpoints ignored by Intellij running Spring Boot with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm attempting to debug a Spring Boot application using IntelliJ 14 Ultimate edition.

The application won't run directly in the IDE (see screenshot at the bottom) because of other issues but runs via the command line using the following command:

```
./gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dserver.port=15020 -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5245"
```

My setup in IntelliJ:

[image]

I added the following to my `build.gradle` to get the profile and port arguments accepted:

```
bootRun { 
    systemProperties =  System.properties 
}
```

The debugger in IntelliJ connects successfully but it will not pause execution on any breakpoints set. From the IntelliJ console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5245', transport: 'socket'
```

Dependency Versions

- Spring: 4.1.3.RELEASE
- Spring Boot: 1.1.8-RELEASE
- spring-boot-gradle-plugin: 1.1.12.RELEASE
- Gradle 2.8

Class path resource error that occurs in IDE and not on CLI:

[image]

Comment: Not knowing anything about the structure of your app, it's hard to say, but in what kind of code are you putting your breakpoints? config, controller, etc?

Comment: Controllers and I also tried on a request listener where I know logging is being called.

Comment: It sounds like IntelliJ is not seeing the same classes as the running app. How did you open the project originally in IntelliJ? Did you just "open" the build.gradle file or do a project import? Sometimes it seems to make a difference.

Comment: Also, have you tried running with `--debug-jvm` rather than configuring it yourself? `./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm` (plus any other args you need). I just noticed you are running really old versions - I assume this was available from the beginning of boot.

Comment: Wow that worked (`--debug-jvm`). Post as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it solved the problem! - I have created an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferred method to enable debugging with Spring Boot is to use the `--debug-jvm` option:

```
./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm
```

Along with any other arguments you need. With the method specified in your post, I think you are actually debugging Gradle, not your application.